# SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins. Where?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get an error message when I run this. Do you know why? I've built it using the Access design view.

```
SELECT  [Sales structure].Cluster ,
        [Sales structure].Country ,
        [Transaction details].[Sales company code] ,
        [Sales structure].[Sales company name] ,
        YEAR([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]) AS [Year] ,
        MONTH([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]) AS [Month] ,
        SUM([Transaction details].[Sales volume LOC]) AS Total ,
        [Transaction details].[Currency code] ,
        Currencies.[CUR/EUR] AS [Currency rate]
FROM    Items ,
        Currencies
        RIGHT JOIN ( [Sales structure]
                     RIGHT JOIN [Transaction details] ON [Sales structure].[Sales company code] = [Transaction details].[Sales company code]
                   ) ON Currencies.[Currency code] = [Transaction details].[Currency code]
GROUP BY [Sales structure].Cluster ,
        [Sales structure].Country ,
        [Transaction details].[Sales company code] ,
        [Sales structure].[Sales company name] ,
        YEAR([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]) ,
        MONTH([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]) ,
        [Transaction details].[Currency code] ,
        Currencies.[CUR/EUR]
HAVING  ( ([Transaction details].[Currency code] = [Currencies].[Currency code]) )
ORDER BY YEAR([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]) ,
        MONTH([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]) ;
```

Comment: This is the offending part: `FROM Items, Currencies`. You are not joining `Items` with the other tables.

Comment: But now I get a different problem. Access complains on "[Transaction details].[Currency code]=[Currencies].[Currency code]" that "your query does not include the specified expression [Transaction details].[Currency code]=[Currencies].[Currency code] as part of an aggregate function

Comment: Please ask a new question

Answer (score 3):

There is no `JOIN` condition between the `Items` and `Currencies` tables. They are simply introduced with a comma.

MS Access is very particular about joins. You may also want to put parentheses around each join as it can have conniptions about missing parentheses, even if the query is syntactically correct without them.

I strongly encourage you to forget that you can join tables using a comma `,` and through putting join conditions in the `WHERE` clause. This is old-style and should be abandoned! Please start using ANSI SQL joins that are introduced (after the first table) with a `JOIN` clause and joined with an `ON` clause. There are many compelling reasons for this--just do some searches online if you want to understand more.

Comment: Further in no database should you ever combine implicit and explicit joins, you will get the wrong reults or errors because the explicit joins are evaluated before the where clauses (can't tell you how many questions I;ve seen wondering what was wrong). In fact, it is a SQL antipattern to use implict joins at all.

Comment: Good points, @HLGEM! I've added some more to my answer to address this aspect.